# VirtualHost always go to default conf

Tags: linux, debian, virtualhost

I got a amazon EC2 running on Debian. And a domain : flavienm.com
The server run Apache 2.4.10

I try to set a subdomain : eyewall:flavienm.com

In my sites-available I got :

- 000-default.conf
- eyewall.flavienm.com.conf
- default-ssl.conf

In my sites-enable I got :

- symlinks to 000-default.conf
- symlinks to eyewall.flavienm.com.conf

In the apache.conf the line : sites-enabled/*.conf is there.

I use UserDir mod, then to flavienm.com/~eyewall I see the page.

I have configured the DNS zone in OVH like that : eyewall.flavienm.com -> CNAME -> flavienm.com.

And the commande apache2ctl -S return that :

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server flavienm.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost flavienm.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost eyewall.flavienm.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eyewall.flavienm.com.conf:1)
```

When I try to access eyewall.flavienm.com it goes to flavienm.com, then what I miss ?

Comment: What do your log file say when you access the domain?

Comment: The log of the main domain flavienm.com log the access but no difference between an access from eyewall.flavienm.com or directly flavienm.com.

Comment: But I found something strange, when I try access eyewall.flavienm.com/index it works I got the good page. The only file on the subdomain eyewall is "index.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Clear the cache of my browser.

Thanks you